# Do all permanent magnets of the same composition and dimensions generate the same magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

For example, assume you have two sintered neodymium magnets that are 10mm x 20mm x 30 mm.

Will these magnets both generate the same magnetic field? Ie, is the field a consequence of the geometry, or the manufacturing process?

If the field is simply a result of the geometry, how do you calculate the magnetic field from the dimensions?

If the field is also a result of the manufacturing process, does the manufacturing process yield a range of field strengths that can then be chosen by the manufacturer? If so, what is this spec called, and how would I calculate the field from the geometry and the spec?

In either case, is there a tolerance, and what is it?

Comment: "same composition" kind of implies  "same manufacturing process" .  Other than the variance in, e.g., the exact sintering power or time, you end up with indistinguishable items and thus the same field strength.

Comment: Perhaps they are made from the same stuff, but there is a magnetization process that could differ? Thus you could have magnets made from the same stuff, and of the same dimensions, but with differing magnetic fields.